# Recycler View repeats background colour

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a songs list in recycler view. and i need to change the background colour of rows previously played.

so in my `onBindViewHolder` i have this.

```
               if(activeAudioIndex > activeList.indexOf(currentSong)) {
                    currentRow.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPink)
                }
```

in this `activeAudioIndex` is the actual index of playing song.

`activeList` is the array used for recyclerView

But i can see changed background colours repeating for unnecessary rows. when i scroll down.

HOW TO FIX THIS ISSUE ?

Comment: Add the adapter code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the 'else' part as well. So your code should look like this :

```
if(activeAudioIndex > activeList.indexOf(currentSong)) {
    currentRow.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorPink)
} else {
    //DEFAULT BACKGROUND COLOR
    currentRow.setBackgroundColor(R.color.another_color)
}
```